# Qt cannot find compiler

Tags: qt, build, set

I was earlier using GCC on DevC++. I am trying to do the same with Qt. but it did not detect my compiler. I tried linking my GCC stuff in DevC++\bin using manual compiler option. It didn't work. Every time I compile my program it says "qt creator needs a compiler set up to build."

I looked for the answers everywhere but I could get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Windows - the installer for Qt typically comes with an included version of GCC, so you can just chose to install it, Qt will use that and automatically do all the configurations.

If you are building Qt yourself, make sure you get an up-to-date version of GCC and carefully follow the instructions.

Qt employs a MOC - a meta object compiler, which generates lots of boilerplate code to make development easier. Meaning you have to run `qmake` before you compile the sources.

I'd recommend to use Qt's own IDE - Creator - it is available on multiple platforms and is pretty good, tailored around Qt's programming idioms and best of all - will take care of the build process and of its requirements as well. It is most certainly better than the DevC++ IDE.

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. I am using Qt creator itself. While installing it did not ask to install GCC or any other compiler. Also it couldn't find GCC installed on system.

Comment: @GauravSaini - it will not ask you, you have to select the compile from the "Tools" category when you customize the installation. You can install a standalone version, but make sure it is compatible with your Qt build, then from Creator->Tools->Build&Run->Compilers you can add it and create a Kit that uses it with your Qt build.

Comment: Also, it will not be named "GCC" but "MinGW", keep that in mind in case you don't find GCC anywhere.